# What does this function do? How does it work?

Tags: javascript

can anyone explain what this code does and how it works?

```
function(a) {
    return !n.isString(a) ? a : a.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")
}
V(a) {
    return !n.isString(a) ? a : a.replace(/%/g,"%25")
}
```

What  does the `!n` after the `return` mean?
What  are these two functions doing?

Comment: That means, if `n` is `false`

Comment: `function(a){...}` this is anonymous function, if this context your code is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part basically means "if a is not a string, return a, otherwise replace all `\` with `\\`.

The second part is about the same, but with `%` and `%25`.

`!n.isString` appears to be "not n.isString" or "is not a string". To understand this better you can think of it as this: `!(n.isString)`, where `n` is the Object/Class that implements a `isString` method.

The `a ? b : c` operator is called a ternary operator and is basically the same as

```
if (a) {
    return b
} else {
    return c
}
```

Comment: !n.isString(a) 
i know that isString(a) return true if a is a string and false otherwise
but the !n and the . between the two i don't get it

Comment: @SeifEddineSlimen what about now?

Comment: It's very clear that's what i think about it.
Thanks!